# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Spring_mvc_sep13/WEB-INF/Asset.jsp] in DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

Please help me solve the issue.
The request is going to the controller class and getting the view name but failing to display the jsp with the error.

I am getting the following warning on the console when the url 'http://localhost:8080/Spring_mvc_sep13/assetController' is typed in the browser.

org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound 
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Spring_mvc_sep13/WEB-INF/Asset.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'Disp'

the web.xml is as follows

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Disp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/Dispatcher-Beans.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Disp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The Dispatcher-Beans.xml file is as follows

```
   <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
   <property name="prefix" ><value>/WEB-INF/</value></property>
   <property name="suffix" ><value>.jsp</value></property>
   </bean>

   <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>

   <bean name="/assetController" class="org.pradeep.controller.AssetController"/>

   <context:component-scan base-package="org.pradeep.controller"></context:component-scan>

   <mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

The controller class is as follows

```
package org.pradeep.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/assetController")
public class AssetController extends AbstractController {

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest arg0,
            HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView mView = new ModelAndView("Asset");

        return mView;
    }

}
```

the folder structure is as follows.
[image]

Comment: check if 'Asset.jsp' is getting correctly deployed in tomcat...jsp should be in 'WebContent' folder and not in WEB-INF

Comment: When I change the tomcat server from 7.0.30 to 7.0.68, it worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the tomcat server 7.0.30, java 1.8 and was getting this error. The jsp was not getting compiled. Therefore i changed the server to 7.0.68 and it solved the issue.